# Using ODK collect, Can I display all questions in single vertical scroll view rather than horizontal scrolling?

Tags: android, odk

I have integrated odk collect in android app (http://docs.opendatakit.org/collect-intro/) to have the dynamic form facility, I did it and now I am able to successfully run the project.
But one of my requirement is to display all the questions in a single page in vertical scrollview, right now in odk colect it is horizontally scrollable…

If yes then what are the changes I need to do in the code?

I tried by making the questionHolder LinearLayout’s orientation as vertical but it did not worked.
Please suggest me the way to go…

Answer (score 0):

You could use appearance 'field-list', I think. Though there may be some issue with logic that refers to fields on the same page (not sure if that's fixed).